# How do I find if an Id is present in the array of team members (which stores user ids)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I have this model of workspace schema in my node js project(model is displayed below)
After the user logs into my application I want to display the information of a workspace only if it is created by him or he is a team member of that workspace

I am able to find the workspaces **created by the user** by the following query

`Workspace.find({creator:req.user._id},function(err,workspaces){
  res.render('home',{
  wokspacses:workspaces
  });
});`

similarly, I also want the workspaces in which the user is the team member
`Workspace.find({creator:req.user._id},function(err,workspaces){
 Workspace.find({team_member:"WHAT SHOULD I WRITE HERE"},function(err,workspaces2){
  res.render('home',{
  wokspacses:workspaces
  wokspacses2:workspaces2
  });
});`

Since team_members is an array simply passing the user id is not yielding the result and workspaces2 remains empty

Thank you for your time !!

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const workspaceSchema = mongoose.Schema({
      name:{
        type:String,
        required:true
      },
      date: {
        type: Date,
        required: true
      },
      creator:{
        type: Object,
        ref: 'User',
        required: true
      },
      team_member: [{ type: Object, ref: 'User' }]
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Workspace',workspaceSchema);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the $in Operator.

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose")
const Schema = mongoose.Schema
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/stackoverflow', {useNewUrlParser: true});

const workspaceSchema = new Schema({
      name:{
        type:String,
        required:true
      },
      date: {
        type: Date,
        required: true
      },
      creator:{
        type: Object,
        ref: 'User',
        required: true
      },
      team_member: [{ type: Object, ref: 'User' }]
});

const WorkspaceModel = mongoose.model('Workspace',workspaceSchema);
const sessionUserId = "5d330f3de87ec83f95504c44" //i.e. req.user._id; 

WorkspaceModel.find({
    $or:[
        { creator: sessionUserId },
        { 
            team_member: { 
                $in: [sessionUserId]
            } 
        }
    ]
}).exec((err, result) => {
    console.log("result", result)
})
```